# Wait just a minute

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

A man goes into a room and sits down.

Suddenly his weight increases, then eventually resumes back to normal.

After several hours - suddenly his weight decreases, then eventually resumes back to normal.

Finally when the man exits the room, his weight is the same as when he went in.

What happened?

**EDIT**: The answer is not "He went in an elevator".

What transpired was not an abnormal event.

Comment: @SteveV not the same answer, but yes I see that it is fairly similar.

Comment: if it is not the same answer, I withdraw my objection, then!

Comment: phew :) I will try to add some edits to clarify how it cannot be an elevator.

Comment: He went in the loo with some food. Some food goes in, some byproduct goes out and the weight goes up and down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

> he got on an airplane! 
> And perhaps it was one of those astronaut training flights where you are weightless for a brief period of time

Comment: That's it! Although the decreasing weight part was supposed to reference the descent of the plane :P